# jdbc prepared statement with oracle NUMBER type

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I have a java application which sets up a jdbc connection to an Orcale database. I am attempting to insert data into the database but am confused when it comes to the oracle NUMBER type. I have three columns in my table which are of these types respectively.

```
NUMBER(38,0)
NUMBER(20,0)
NUMBER(16,0)
```

My first question is what type of java type should I put the data in, in order to use it in a prepared statement.

My second question is what set operation can I use in a prepared statement in order to insert the data.

Lets just assume we are working with NUMBER(38,0). Would I set the java type to a BigInteger? If I had an integer 1 would it be

```
 BigInteger one = new BigInteger(1);
```

Then in my preparedStatement it would be

```
 PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE(bigInt) VALUES(?)");
 pstmt.setLong(1, one);
```

This seems to not work, so I assume that this is not correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try setBigDecimal() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBigDecimal(int, java.math.BigDecimal)

Comment: @BhavikShah I tried setBigDecimal, it is still giving me ORA-00911: invalid character. I am even building and printing out the sql insert statement and then pasting it into sql developer and it works fine. It is only failing within the java.

Comment: I followed a few SO questions similar to this..no answers unfortunately :( ..one answer however suggested to store it as string..does this work for you?

Comment: @medium - is that your actual statement, or have you edited it? Just wondering if you've left a semicolon at the end of the command string - which would work in SQL Developer but throw ORA-00911 through JDBC.

Comment: I figured out the issue.. I am embarrased to say that in my preparedStatment string I added a semicolon at the end conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE(bigInt) VALUES(?);"); Sorry.. thank you for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setLong()` cannot take a `BigInteger`. If you truly have values exceeding the range of `long` in your database, then you may need to use `setBigDecimal()`, as there is no `setBigInteger()`, and your variable would have to be of type `BigDecimal`. If `long` encompasses the range of values in your database, then just use `long` and `setLong()`.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this way:

```
 oracle.sql.NUMBER numberValue = new oracle.sql.NUMBER(bigIntegerValue);
 cs.setObject(id, numberValue, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
```

where `bigIntegerValue` is an instance of `java.math.BigInteger`, it works for me

Comment: wont it be performance issue as it type casts the bigIntger to Number